# I need a regular expression that will receive exactly 9 digits (only numbers)

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will only allow exactly 9 digits.
i will use this expression for an asp control validator to validate a textbox.
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

How about `^\d{9}$` which will use `\d` to be any digit, then make sure there is nothing but that on the line

Comment: @MatanTal  - If it works for you, you can accept it with the check.